# Split GEE FeatureCollection according to latitude

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have an `ee.FeatureCollection` with points across the globe. As a pre-processing step, I need to split it according to whether the points are in the Northern or Southern hemisphere.

Conceptually it's not a big deal, but since I am new to GEE and its JavaScript syntax, I can't get it to work.

Consider we have the FeatureCollection `myPoints`:

```
var myPoints = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-60,-20), {'id': 0}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(140,-20), {'id': 1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-70,10), {'id': 2}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(80,40), {'id': 3}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(10,50), {'id': 4}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(20, -10), {'id': 5})
]);
```

I think it should work something like:

1. Define a function "GetLatitude" which gets the latitude of each point.
   I thought of `myPoints.geometry()` but I don't succeed at indexing the resulting list of lists
   `myPoints.geometry()[0][1]` is not the way to go.
2. Define a function "FilterHemisphere" that serves as a handle to split positive latitudes to the
   Northern hemisphere, and negative latitudes to Southern hemisphere. JavaScript has a function
   `Math.sign()` to tell positive numbers from negative numbers, but I don't see any equivalent under
   Docs->ee.Number.
3. Apply the functions to myPoints. I thought in proper GEE JavaScript it should be something like
   `myPoints.map(GetLatitude).filter(FilterHemisphere)`

I wonder if anyone could help me with defining the functions and how to apply them in proper JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is spot on. However, earth engine has many in-built functions that make it easy to do geometric manipulations. In-built functions also run faster as they are innately parallelised.

So consider using the function `ee.FeatureCollection.filterBounds()`. It filters a featurecollection conditional on the geometries lying inside a pre-defined polygon. Then just define two polygons, one for north and one for south.

[Here is the complete code classifying the points you defined.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/704ca1daafe69e9c820e135fc5ec0525)

[image]